# texdiff on plain tex files

Tags: pdftex, plain-tex, latexdiff

I have two TeX files that I need to compare, and I thought texdiff could do this for me. Unfortunately, in the manual page, it reads

> For texdiff to work, the following LaTeX code must be inserted 
>   in the preamble of the LaTeX document:
>
> ```
> \usepackage{xcolor} \usepackage{ulem} \usepackage{changebar}
> \newcommand\TLSins[1]{\cbstart{}\textcolor{ins}{\uline{#1}}\cbend{}}
> \newcommand\TLSdel[1]{\cbdelete{}\textcolor{del}{\sout{#1}}}
> ```

Now, I'm a bit lost as I have never actually used plain TeX and using LaTeX code inside a TeX file is obviously not going to work.

### Example:

Let's consider a very simple plain TeX example. If you use a file with the following content:

```
Let $D$ be a subset of $\bf R$ and let $f \colon D \to
{\bf R}$ be a real-valued function on $D$. The function $f$ is said to be
{\it continuous} on $D$ if, for all $\epsilon > 0$ and for all $x \in D$,
there exists some $\delta > 0$ (which may depend on $x$) such that if $y
\in D$ satisfies $$|y - x| < \delta$$ then $$|f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon.$$

\bye
```

With `pdftex file.tex` this can easily be converted to

[image]

Now, if you make a change in the file and store it under a different name, you can run

```
texdiff file1.tex file2.tex diff.tex
```

you will have the following content inside `diff.tex`

```
Let $D$ be a subset of $\bf R$ and let $f \colon D \to
{\bf R}$ be a real-valued function on $D$. The function $f$ is said to be
{\it continuous} on $D$ if, for all $\epsilon > 0$ and for all $x \in D$,
there exists some $\delta > 0$ \protect\TLSins{(which may depend on $x$)} such that if $y
\in D$ satisfies $$|y - x| < \delta$$ then $$|f(y) - f(x)| < \protect\TLSdel{\epsilon$$ should hold.}
\protect\TLSins{\epsilon.$$}

\bye
```

The commands `\TLSins` and `TLSdel` don't exist in plain `TeX,` and I cannot only put `\usepackage` and `\newcommand` inside this file. This would not work.

**Question:** How must the header look like to define the required commands correctly in plain TeX?

Comment: Is [this](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/02/16/using-latexdiff-for-marking-changes-to-tex-documents.html) helpful?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The problem is that I have *plain tex* files. I too used latexdiff successfully on LaTeX documents and since I found it so helpful, I want to use it on plain tex documents a colleague sent me.

Comment: I have never tried this but as far as I can see Latexdiff should work on plain tex files too.

Comment: @Andrew I have extended my question to show exactly that the problem is not `texdiff` itself, but the output it creates, because, in the resulting diff, there are LaTeX commands while I need to use TeX to compile the file.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your problem now (sorry for being slow!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [changebar](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/changebar) and [ulem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ulem) packages do not seem to have plain TeX equivalents but for colour you can just `\input color`. With some care (using `\ifmmode...\fi` etc), you could get by using `{\em ...}` and `\underline{...}` in place of  [ulem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ulem) ([changebar](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/changebar) would be harder).

The simplest way to get [texdiff](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/texdiff) to work is to add the following code to the top of your diff file:

```
\input color
\def\TLSins#1{{\color{blue}#1}}
\def\TLSdel#1{{\color{red}#1}}
```

This does not add emphasis or underlining for the differences, and there are no change-bars, but it does it does show where the changes are:

[image]

Of course, this will be subject to the usual vagaries of (la)texdiff.

Comment: Good answer, but the package is `ulem` not `uelm`. Spelling the package name correctly seems worthwhile and worth correcting in your answer so readers are not misinformed.